# Write a Script to install an application under wine

Tags: command-line, wine, scripts

I have a non-techy friend who's giving Ubuntu a shot and I'm basically undertaking the challenge of trying to make it as painless as possible.
He would like to install iTunes on his machine but I'd rather he not have to screw around with Wine just yet.
Is there a way that I could write a script that installs iTunes under Wine for him?

**The essence of what I'm asking is: can software be installed under wine via command line?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wine is installed on his PC the script is just:

```
#!/bin/bash
wine iTunesInstallerName.exe
```

Put that together with the iTunes installer in a directory and tell him to run the script.
It will start the installation process.

Comment: An even better idea would just to make an all-in-one script that installs Wine, adds the PPAs, uses wget to download the iTunes installer to the /tmp directory, and then run wine iTunesInstallerName.exe.